# Variation of Nesbitt Inequality with the geometric mean

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The problem is the following: 
Prove the inequality: $ \frac{\sqrt{pq}}{p + q + 2r}+\frac{\sqrt{qr}}{q + r+2p}+\frac{\sqrt{pr}}{p + r+2q}≤3/4 $ for $p, q, r>0$ real numbers.
 
I could prove a weaker inequality using the rearrangement inequality, but i haven't been able to solve this inequality. If you substitute $\sqrt{pq}$ with $\frac{p+q}{2}$ you get the famous Nesbitt inequality.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that you have to prove that it is smaller than equal to (not greater than equal to)

Comment: Solution on AoPS? https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1973507p13687896

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not really understand how anhduy98 solved the problem. Can you please explain a bit. I am not that advanced of a problem solver :-). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think anhduy98 used GM-QM in the first step. I still do not know what anhduy98 used in the second step.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{pq}}{p+q+2r}\leq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^2}{p+q+2r}\leq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(\sqrt{p})^2}{p+r}+\frac{\sqrt{q})^2}{q+r}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{p}{p+r}+\frac{q}{q+r}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{p}{p+r}+\frac{r}{r+p}\right)=\frac{3}{4}.$$
I used the following C-S:
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{c^2}{d}\geq\frac{(a+c)^2}{b+d},$$ where $b$ and $d$ are positives.

Here $a=\sqrt{p},$ $b=p+r,$ $c=\sqrt{q}$ and $d=q+r.$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still did not understand how you used C-S inequality. I would appreciate if you could answer my question.

Comment: @user802105 I added something. See now.

Comment: Now i understand completely. Thanks for all who helped.

Comment: @user802105 You are welcome!